# 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python

I am trying to print the columns that contain tu anywhere in the title.
According to [String Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) this should work, but I get an error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

I am trying to have have a dataframe with the columns containing tu only

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           scale = 10,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'car':X[:,0],
                                  'ball':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3': 5,
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.str.contains("tu")]
print(spike_cols)
```

Comment: Pretty sure its for the same reason that `'hello'.str()` throws the same error.  Strings in python don't have an attribute or method named `str()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, .str doesn't change the type into a string, try it like this:

`spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "tu" in str(col)]`

Comment: any ideas how to have it back in a dataframe – Victor just now   edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in`

```
spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "tu" in col]
```

Looks like you are looking for.

```
df.filter(like='tu')
```

Comment: any ideas how to have it back in a dataframe

Comment: Sorry what do you mean 'have it back in a dataframe' ?

Comment: now the output is of type list, can we use these columns to construct a dataframe, which is the type of df.

Comment: `df.filter(like='tu')` this should help. You will get the DF which has 'tu' in column name

Comment: sorry it is actually __df.loc[:,spike_cols]__